# Disable autocomplete for all jquery datepicker inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable `autocomplete` for all inputs using jquery ui datepicker without doing this to every input manually.
How could be this done?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.datepicker').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
});
```

> in anycase you have not mentioned in
>   your question that this is coming from
>   an ajax call!

Comment: For some reason this code works only after first focus for the input.
I changed 'focus' to 'hover' and it works.
Thanks

Comment: Anyone attempting to use this solution in 2015 (vs 2010 when the answer was posted) should use [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) instead. Unless of course you are using a very old version of jQuery.

Comment: On older version (mine 1.7.1) use `focus` instead of `click`

Comment: Setting the attribute on the html did not work (Chrome forcing autocomplete) but this does!  Hopefully Chrome doesn't nerf it (autocomplete was rendering over the top of the datepicker widget, rendering it useless)

Comment: The answer by @djdd87 worked better for me.  Plus it's a bit more concise.  Chrome really is annoying with the autocomplete.  Honestly, it should be a property built in with datepicker, imo.

Comment: @deebs yes you are right, i have asked to remove my answer. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but google brought me here for this answer.

Comment: The question specifically states to not add it manually for each input, this answer should not any upvotes, imo.

Comment: I should not, however it is very useful for people landing here (including me) who don't particularly care about jQuery. Hence the upvotes (including mine).

Answer (score 17):

Assign a css class to your datepickers, i.e. "datepicker", then do the following:

```
$(".datepicker").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: I am putting this code in my main layout, i think it's being executed on current inputs in the DOM. When loading an ajax form the newly created inputs still has autocomplete on.

Comment: If an element is created after your code runs, or in this case, if a css class is assigned after dynamically you need to use "live"

Answer (score 7):

This works for me (It was tested on Chrome v70.0.3538.110):

```
            $("#dtpckr([readonly])").datepicker()
            .focus(function() {
                $(this).prop("autocomplete", "off");
                //              return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me perfectly.

```
      $("#autocmpldisablechk").click(function () {

        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) { // enable autocomplete

            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                disabled: false
            });

        }
        else { // disable autocomplete
            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                disabled: true
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end there are several rants on StackOverflow on this. Putting in default dates worked for me. ;<). Datepicker specific.