# Correct syntax for CJuiDatePicker disabling autocomplete in Yii?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, yii, datepicker

Any ideas what is the correct syntax for disabling autocomplete statement ?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'dlivraison',
    'language'=>'fr',
    'options'=>array(
        'dateFormat'=>'dd/mm/yy',
        'showOn'=>'button',
        'buttonText'=>'CAL',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'autoComplete'=>'off',
        'size'=>8,
    ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: are you talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2765196/720508) ?

Comment: yes I've seen it but I was thinking there should be a way from inside the widget ?

Comment: OK so finally follow your advice. The interesting things is it does not need, for a single datepicker, to Assign a css class. As in my sample I could access it from the model(here Tcommande) + attribute so the $('#Tcommande_dlivraison').attr('autocomplete','off'); from your link works like a charm.

Comment: ok..that sounds good, glad to help

Comment: btw, could `'htmlOptions=>array('autocomplete'=>'off')'` work? instead of `'htmlOptions'=>array('autoComplete'=>'off'),` , maybe it was just a spelling mistake?

Comment: This is one of the many (many....) syntaxes I tried w/o success !

Comment: just to be sure are you also talking about the `autocomplete` vs `autoComplete` ?

Comment: hehe... Because you insist... I feel it should be something wrong !!!
My mistake was the missing closing parenthesis of the option array so the htmlOptions was never taken in account. I correct the answer accordingly... tks again...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I put the full code will be more clear for further readers...

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'dlivraison',
    'language'=>'fr',
    'options'=>array(
        'dateFormat'=>'dd/mm/yy',
        'showOn'=>'button',
        'buttonText'=>'CAL',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'autocomplete'=>'off',
        'size'=>8,
    ),
  ));
```

Comment: then now it should work without the script? try and lemme know

Comment: anyway, you should accept your own answer, future visitors will know how to solve it.