# How to clear history of DatePicker in jQuery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, datetimepicker

I have two jQuery Date Pickers but when I put the cursor inside each of the date-pickers, all dates that were previously selected are shown as a list.

I want to clear all those dates that were previously selected.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable autocomplete for all jquery datepicker inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765196/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is called autocomplete
You can learn about this attr in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) or [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

VIA HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="myid" autocomplete="off">
```

VIA JQUERY

```
$('.datepicker').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
});
```

VIA JQUERY ALL DATEPICKERS (class named .datepicker)

```
$(".datepicker").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: i selected your answer as the best not only because it solved my problem but also it was based on the requirement tagged which was Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser is autocompleting the field. You can stop this behaviour simply by turning off autocomplete on the `input` element:

```
<input id="datepicker" autocomplete="off" />
```

Read more about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

Comment: Thanks, so helpful but wanted Jquery answer.

Answer (score 0):

var todayDate = new Date();

$(function() {

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: todayDate   
});
```

});