# How to prevent before inserted value in html input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know how I describe this, but you can understand what I want after seeing this below image

[image]

In this picture here is an input field which maintains input date, I mean jQuery datepicker, everything is fine but when I inserted some values before now I can't see the datepicker it's shoowing before inserted values & below that have datepicker.

How I prevent this auto populate after a click to the input field, actually I don't need this, I want to show only datepicker.

Thanks

Comment: please share some code

Comment: Try `autocomplete="off"` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields#Disabling_autocompletion)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable autocomplete for all jquery datepicker inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765196/608639) and [How to clear history of DatePicker in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51476868/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the autocomplete like below, or where you set the config

```
$('.datepicker').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
});
```