# CalendarExtender -- don't want recently selected dates

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-ajax

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent the Ajax CalendarExtender from displaying recently selected dates (like the 2018-03-05, etc. in below screenshot)?  I also wasn't sure if this was a browser feature, but I have unselected all of the predictive options in my Chrome browser, cleared all history/cache, shut the browser down completely and it's still showing the dates.  This is an ASP.NET, C# application.

I've never had much success with getting jQuery to work, but here is what I have so far:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('tbStartDate').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
    });
    $('tbEndDate').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");  
    });
</script>
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="tbStartDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbEndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="tbEndDate"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

But I'm getting the "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function at VendorFreightCalc.aspx:16, which points at the first jQuery line above.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable autocomplete for all jquery datepicker inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765196/disable-autocomplete-for-all-jquery-datepicker-inputs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this question:

[Disable autocomplete for all jquery datepicker inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765196/disable-autocomplete-for-all-jquery-datepicker-inputs)

Basically, you want to turn off autocomplete for that field.

(UPDATE)

Maybe try the non-jquery options for turning off autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" name="field1" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```